# Sort function for std:sort with & parametr c++

Tags: c++, sorting

I want to use reference to my instance as a parameter of sort function.

I have `vector<CMail> log`, in class `CMail` have function which compare as I want.

And a want to sort `log` so I have:

```
bool sortFunction(CMail a, CMail b){
  return (a.CompareByTimeStamp(b) < 0) ? true : false;
}
```

and then

```
sort(log.begin(), log.end(), sortFunction);
```

It works fine. But can I have parameters of function as a reference like this?

```
bool sortFunction(CMail &a, CMail &b){
...
}
```

When I did this, my code didn't compile.

How can I do this?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I believe they have to be `const CMail &`. Edit: [yes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort).

Comment: Also, as a general rule when asking questions, you should include the full compiler error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short: `const`ness.
You need:

```
bool sortFunction(const CMail& a, const CMail& b){
  return (a.CompareByTimeStamp(b) < 0);
}
```

Which also means your signature for `CompareByTimeStamp` must be:

```
int CompareByTimeStamp(const Cmail& other) const; // (inside class Cmail {...};)
//                      ^ b is const         ^ a is const
```

See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort).
This is all because comparing two objects should not change them.